# Excel. Getting #NAME? error with regular functions

Tags: excel

I am developing an excel file that works in my computer, but when I send it to a college he gets a `#NAME? error`.

This error traces back to a cell containing the following formula:

`=IF(ISFORMULA(Control!A13);HLOOKUP("Income";Data!$1:$2;2;0);Control!A13)`

As far as I know, the error would mean that excel is not recognizing some of the functions. `IF` and `HLOOKUP`are extensively used in the spreedsheet causing no problem, and `ISFORMULA` is only used once, so it is to blame.

- Could it be that he does not have the function `ISFORMULA`? It is not such an unusual function though.
- Any suggestions as to what we could try to make it work?

Comment: Why not you try this: `=IF(ISFORMULA(Control!A13),HLOOKUP("Income",Data!$1:$2,2,0),Control!A13)` I have just replaced semicolon with comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isformula-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5), `ISFORMULA` was introduced in Excel 2013.

So anything older than that will not have it.

With older versions you can create a quick UDF:

```
Function myisformula(rng As Range) As Boolean
    myisformula = rng.HasFormula
End Function
```

Then just call that in your formula:

```
=IF(myisformula(Control!A13);HLOOKUP("Income";Data!$1:$2;2;0);Control!A13)
```

Comment: `MyIsFormula = rng.HasFormula`?  [HasFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasformula)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook that is what I get for typing in the answer and not thinking.  Thank you.

Comment: Seeing as it was you answering I sat here for a good few minutes thinking "what have I missed?" before I commented.  All I could think was `HasFormula` can work on the whole range and not just a single cell, but that's not really a problem.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have never professed to be anything but human, and as such, I am subject to making errors.  I usually do not take criticism as anything but constructive, so do not fear commenting on my errors.  It is how we make the answer better for not only the OP but those who come afterward.  Again thank you.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!